# How can I tell typescript that my function returns a class that is extended by a specific class?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following classes:

```
class A {
    constructor($elem: JQuery<HTMLElement>) {
        $elem.data('plugin', this);
    }

    inheritedMethod() {
        ...
    }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor($elem: JQuery<HTMLElement>) {
        super($elem);
    }

    specificMethodB() {
        ...
    }
}

class C extends A {
    constructor($elem: JQuery<HTMLElement>) {
        super($elem);
    }
}

getAishClass($elem: JQuery<HTMLElement>): A {
    return $elem.data('plugin');
    // this function will return either a class B or a class C
}


const $bDiv = jQuery("<div></div>");
const $cDiv = jQuery("<div></div>");

new B($bDiv);
new C($cDiv);

const thisIsAC = getAishClass($cDiv);

thisIsAC.specificMethodC(); // this tells me that I have an error, A does not implement this method
```

I could tell `getAishClass` that it returns a type of `any`, but is there a way, in which I could explicitly specify, that the value returned by the function will be a class, which **definitely** extends `class A`?

Basically, in the above example, both I (the programmer) and the programm "could" know that `getAishClass` will return an instance of `C`. But considering the above example, there are situations, where I will call the `getAishClass` method on a jQuery element, which I do not know what kind of `A` it implements. In these situations, I would like to get type hinting for at least the methods in the `A` class, but in all the other situations, I don't want ts complaining that the function is not implemented.

Comment: uh, just `A`?  or maybe `B | C` if you care about extension?  Maybe I'm not sure about what you're asking

Comment: @jcalz I have a bunch of classes that extend the `A` class, and in the future, I will have a bunch more. It would suffice if that function would know, that it returns something that is extending the `A` class. My problem is, that basically, I could tell the function that it returns an instance of the `A` class, but then my IDE complains if I would like to use a method specifically from the `B` or `C` classes respectively. I will update my question with a bit more info.

Comment: Then at the point where you call `getAishClass` you'll have to cast the result to `B` or `C`; only the calling code knows which derived class the instance actually is supposed to be. Unless it's possible to figure out from the arguments which derived class is being returned?

Comment: Does this question depend on JQuery?  If so it should be tagged; if not the example code should be made into a [mcve] that doesn't depend on it (or at least that includes all necessary config).  Ideally any code should be droppable into a standalone IDE like [The TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) so we can play around with it easily.

Comment: AFAICT the types of `$bDiv` and `$cDiv` are precisely the same, so there's no way for Typescript to differentiate between passing in `$cDiv` vs passing in `$bDiv`. I think your only option is to write `const thisIsAC = getAishClass($cDiv) as C;`, you can then follow with `C`-specific methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
`

class A {
  someMethod() {}
}

class B extends A {
  someMethodB() {}
}

class C extends A {
  someMethodC() {}
}

class D {}

function myfunc(): A {
  return new B();
}

const btype = <B>myfunc();
btype.someMethodB(); // no problem to IDE here

function myfunc2(): A {

    // return new A(); // this is fine.

    // return new B(); // also fine

    // return new C(); // also fine

    // return new D(); // this is not fine, ts will complain. 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is... when you call `new B(elem)`, you are hoping that the compiler will do something to the type of `elem` to remember that it has been called with `new B()`.  That's not the normal way TypeScript works.

You can *kind of*, *sort* of do something like this with [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) so that the type of `elem` will be *narrowed* when you call a function with it as a parameter.  Unfortunately, you cannot do that with constructors, only functions or methods.  Meaning we need to make our own `new`-like function that takes a constructor and a JQuery element and narrows that element type:

```
function magicNew<T>(ctor: new (e: JQuery<HTMLElement>) => T, elem: JQuery<HTMLElement>):
    asserts elem is JQuery<HTMLElement> & { __plugindata__: T } {
    new ctor(elem);
}
```

So instead of calling `new B(elem)`, you call `magicNew(B, elem)`.

Oh, and even with that I'm lying to the compiler.  I'm pretending that when you call `magicNew(B, $bDiv)` the implementation is adding a property named `__plugindata__` of type `B` to `$bDiv`.  This isn't happening of course at runtime; it's more like it's making the return type of `$bDiv.data('plugin')` equal to `B`, but that is not something we can use later in `getAishClass`.  The lie allows us to force the compiler to remember something "extra" about `$bDiv` after we call `magicNew()`.

Now `getAishClass()` looks like this:

```
function getAishClass<T extends JQuery<HTMLElement>>($elem: T): T extends {__plugindata__: infer U} ? U : A {
    return $elem.data('plugin');
}
```

Here we are looking at the `$elem` passed in.  If the compiler thinks it has a `__plugindata__` property it gives us that property type; otherwise it gives us just `A`.  So we pull out that phantom property if the compiler thinks it's there.

This gives you the behavior you're asking for, I think:

```
const $bDiv = jQuery("<div></div>");
const $cDiv = jQuery("<div></div>");

magicNew(B, $bDiv); // do this instead of new B($bDiv)
magicNew(C, $cDiv); // do this instead of new C($cDiv)

const thisIsAC = getAishClass($cDiv);

thisIsAC.specificMethodC(); // no error
```

Yay!

Is it worth it?  It's got many moving pieces that are weird and possibly fragile. If this is for some piece of production code I'd stay away from it.  If it's for personal use I might use it.  In any case I hope it gives you some idea about the limitations and edges of TypeScript's abilities.

Good luck!

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wFIEUCuBTKATzgDMoIQ4ByAKwEd8iqBYAKDYGMAbNdAQTgBvNnFFwOEAHaoYUHBxjQAFABI8XPCABcmXAUIAeABIAVALIAZAKIaQeSTAB8ASiEixHtbYB0AE2QwyEpUYFw4AObAklQANHAwABbAqM4A3O6iAL5sGXBRCQTAMHi+ZniJEL5KrsKsHh4A9A252aytnDyo6ABCcHgAHsWSvvxudWIS0rLyilCq6po62IyGppY2mvZONbkeqDhgBPO2aS0546KohxzAJMAcZRW+3dVj9WJNZ23n3LxwAMJ9Qb2EZwAS1DyTGRyBTKLyLXQrYzmay2LYuN7vOD7Q5zeEgU4XOCtPbXW73R4JSr-V61L7tVgkHCSBTAKRwcLlPjJBL-TqoAwmIFDUHLfTI9ZohyORzHBEmZw6IUDEXoQQAfXVoQiUX8gU1OiiJAIcAAqpk4AB+M1wHTg3JQco4KCSOD4vwBIIhMKRaKEhlMlkwNmukDISIcAByeAA7oLZbCoDpJLG4Eo8Es9EQJajNtLXABeRxwExxBbaRHita5uz5rS5XgEGDoct5dBi7PVja1pxwABkQjgmu1vr1yANJeJmNEKZj4lm6ZO6W+7FYUPgKgARgARYAANzgBbgNCzhCUACIDL5944DA1r3vHOfCeu3RxdwejyeVherze7w+T6EmwYYRtGMZKN0cRbh+aRwE0cC+BA8RJOgUQyHgyC+HAEAkHAs5wC8MH7s4IHhvc4FKP80HviRqTwQ0iHIYkyR5FMmHYbh+GpjSKi0XupGrq+LGoAAkqgfCAkenIwNyqC8vyqj8cBrAieJkneFceA3HcDzlFSvg0nBbBAA)